# How to destroy first js onload when there is a triger from the first onload

Tags: javascript

As you will see from my fiddle below, I am trying but need much more practice, and some help, Please.

I have a select box that loads up to 4 div's. I have a second select box, that will only be shown, if there is more than 1 selected from the first select box.

My problem is, when I change the first select box to zero, although it removes the second select box, it doesn't remove the div's loaded by it.

Any advice Please.

HTML

```
<html>
<div>
 <label>Adults</label>
  <select id='Adults'>
   <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div style='display:none;' id='1Adult'>First Adult information</div>
 <div style='display:none;' id='2Adults'>Second Adult information</div>
 <div style='display:none;' id='3Adults'>Third Adult information</div>
 <div style='display:none;' id='4Adults'>Fourth Adult information</div>
 <div style='display:none;' id='ChildSelector'>
  <label>Children</label>
   <select id='Children'>
   <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='1Child'>First Child information</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='2Children'>Second Child information</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='3Children'>Third Child information</div>
</html>
```

JS 
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Adults').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value == '0')
      {
        $("#1Adult").hide();
        $("#2Adults").hide();
        $("#3Adults").hide();
        $("#4Adults").hide();
        $("#ChildSelector").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#1Adult").show();
        $("#2Adults").hide();
        $("#3Adults").hide();
        $("#4Adults").hide();
        $("#ChildSelector").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2')
      {
        $("#1Adult").show();
        $("#2Adults").show();
        $("#3Adults").hide();
        $("#4Adults").hide();
        $("#ChildSelector").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '3')
      {
        $("#1Adult").show();
        $("#2Adults").show();
        $("#3Adults").show();
        $("#4Adults").hide();
        $("#ChildSelector").show();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '4')
      {
        $("#1Adult").show();
        $("#2Adults").show();
        $("#3Adults").show();
        $("#4Adults").show();
        $("#ChildSelector").show();
      }
     });
     });
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#Children').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '0')
      {
        $("#1Child").hide();
        $("#2Children").hide();
        $("#3Children").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '1')
      {
        $("#1Child").show();
        $("#2Children").hide();
        $("#3Children").hide();

```
  }
  else if ( this.value == '2')
  {
    $("#1Child").show();
    $("#2Children").show();
    $("#3Children").hide();

  }
  else if ( this.value == '3')
  {
    $("#1Child").show();
    $("#2Children").show();
    $("#3Children").show();

  }

 });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeteInSpain/ytg7hey7/2/

Comment: Move the correct jsFiddle to the question. Don't leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really dirty way would be to set the Children select element's value back to 0, so it will remove the elements itself.

```
if ( this.value == '0')
{
    //...
    $("#Children").val(0); //Set it back to 0
    $("#Children").trigger("change"); //Call the listeners
}
```

Or you could restructure your HTML, so that the

```
<div style='display:none;' id='1Child'>First Child information</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='2Children'>Second Child information</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='3Children'>Third Child information</div>
```

block is inside the `<div style='display:none;' id='ChildSelector'>`

Comment: Thanks Zenorbi, the dirty way works well. Changing the structure just leaves them open, as soon as anything from the first select box is selected. My eventual aim is to reset <input> box's to empty, if the divs are not shown. One step at a time eh? Thanks again. PS, Fiddle updates here http://jsfiddle.net/PeteInSpain/ytg7hey7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use

remove() as well..

```
$("#ChildSelector").hide().remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Thanks elad but that didn't help, it removed the selector and oprevented it from working until a refresh, but still left the Div's shown.

Comment: Could you provide a step by step instructions to recreate the scenario you wish to amend ?

Comment: Hi elad, This is a part of a registration form, for a booking system, where the customer can select how many adults and how many children. Then supply names for them. If there are no adults selected, there should not be any children selectable. The end result will be a confirmation screen, to show all details and then a confirm buttom. I hope this explains enough.